# Calling Parametrized function from jquery ajax process parameters value as NULL

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, postgresql

I am using Jquery ajax to call java webservice its getting connected fine but with parameters value as null.

**JQUERY :**

```
var obj = { hname: $("#txtRuleName").val(), hdates: $("#txtRuleDates").val(), hremark: $("#txtRuleRemark").val(), isDelete: false, created_date: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', updated_date: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' };

     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            //crossOrigin: true,
            url: "http://localhost:portnumber/PostGresTestDB/rest/db/insert",
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj)        

        });`
```

**JAVA WEBSERIVE FUNCTION :**

```
  @Path("/db")
public class DBOperaions {

    @GET
    @Path("/insert")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public String InsertDBData(@PathParam("hname") String hname,
            @PathParam("hdates") String hdates,
            @PathParam("hremark") String hremark,
            @PathParam("isDelete") boolean isDelete,
            @PathParam("created_date") String created_date,
            @PathParam("updated_date") String updated_date) {

//DB Dumping Code
}
```

**WEBBROWSER CONSOL :**

```
http://localhost:portnumber/PostGresTestDB/rest/db/insert?callback=jsonCallback&{%22hname%22:%22sdfsfd%22,%22hdates%22:%2205/05/2015,%2005/06/2015,%2005/07/2015,%2005/08/2015,%2005/09/2015,%2005/10/2015,%2005/11/2015,%2005/12/2015,%2005/13/2015,%2005/14/2015,%2005/15/2015,%2005/16/2015%22,%22hremark%22:%22fdfsdfsfd%22,%22isDelete%22:false,%22created_date%22:%22CURRENT_TIMESTAMP%22,%22updated_date%22:%22CURRENT_TIMESTAMP%22}&_=1423111725889
```

But in webservice paramets values are

```
hname =null
hdates = null
hremark =null
isDelete = false // as this is boolean feild
created_date=null
updated_date = null
```

because of this, service fills all null  data to table.

Can anybody tells me why this is happening?

Comment: you should try to use obj.hname because data you are sending as obj.check in firebug.

Comment: @Basavaraj Where could i use obj.hname?

Comment: I think you need `@QueryParam`, not `@PathParam` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam

Comment: I have tried @QueryParam but it still give same null Still identifying what exactely happning